# How to modify my code to only get the time portion of a date?

Tags: java, date

I've got the following code:

```
Date time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").parse("8:00");
```

When I call `time.toString()`, the following is produced:

`Thu Jan 01 08:00:00 CET 1970`

Is there any way I can extract just the `8:00` from it? I have searched far and wide and have not found any way to do it using the standard SimpleDateFormat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

recycle your original `SimpleDateFormat` Object

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm")
Date time = format.parse("8:00");
String outString = format.format(time);
```

in case you were wondering, [Here's some more information on DateTime Masks](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/eglce/v1r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.eglce.lr.doc/topics/regl_core_date_format.html)

Comment: Can the same be applied to extract "Wed Feb 20 2013" from "Wed Feb 20 00:00:00 CET 2013"?

Comment: @DotNET  I posted a link which has some information on what else you can do with dateTime masks.  http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/eglce/v1r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.eglce.lr.doc%2Ftopics%2Fregl_core_date_format.html

Comment: Note: `SimpleDateFormat` is not thread safe. So you should make absolutely sure that you're creating it threadlocal and not be assigning it as applicationwide/static/instance variable or so.

Answer (score 3):

> When I call time.toString(), the following is produced

Yes, it would be - because you're calling `Date.toString`. A `Date` value has no concept of format.

> Is there any way I can extract just the 8:00 from it?

Whenever you want to convert to a string, you should use a `DateFormat`. So use the same format that you parsed in.

Alternatively, use [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), which has a [`LocalTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html) type specifically for "time of day", and has a handy `parse` method. You should *still* use a [formatter](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) every time you want to convert to a string, but at least the value will be easier to work with and more descriptive before then.

```
LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.parse("8:00");
```

To format this, you can use something like [`ISODateTimeFormat.hourMinute()`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html#hourMinute()) or if you might have more precision, perhaps `ISODateTimeFormat.hourMinuteSecond()` - see the docs for all of the many options available.

Comment: Regarding edits to this answer, the original Question was about parsing the string `"8:00"`.

Comment: @BasilBourque: Right, hadn't spotted that. Will change it again :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the same SimpleDateFormat instance to format date into string.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
Date time = sdf.parse("8:00");
System.out.println(sdf.format(time));
```

This will print:

```
08:00
```

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

Existing answers are correct but use the legacy date-time API, which was the right thing to do in 2012.

In March 2014, the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html) supplanted the legacy date-time API. Since then, it has been strongly recommended to switch to `java.time`, the modern date-time API.

The `java.time` API has [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) to represent just time.

```
String strTime = "8:00";
DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(strTime, parser);
System.out.println(time);

// An example of formatting time to a custom format
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
String formatted = time.format(formatter);
System.out.println(formatted);
```

**Output:**

```
08:00
08:00:00
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/5r3fMx)

Learn about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**

Answer (score 0):

[java.util.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) class represents a specific instant in time, with millisecond precision.

**API says [java.util.Date.toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString%28%29)**

> Converts this Date object to a String of the form:
>   dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy

In order to format date's use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class

```
    System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(time));
```